# Hibernate 5 InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl without database connection

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to upgrade from Hibernate 4.3.11.Final to 5.6.15.Final and came across an issue while trying to build my SessionFactory without a database connection. My current code is as follows:

```
private SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setProperty("show_sql", "true");

        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).build();

        MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl buildingOptions = new MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl(serviceRegistry);
        BootstrapContextImpl bootstrapContext = new BootstrapContextImpl(serviceRegistry, buildingOptions);
        buildingOptions.setBootstrapContext(bootstrapContext);

        InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl metadataCollector = new InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl(bootstrapContext, buildingOptions);

        MetadataBuildingContext metadataBuildingContext = new MetadataBuildingContextRootImpl(bootstrapContext, buildingOptions,
                metadataCollector);

        /*
         * Modify metadataCollector here
         */

        MetadataImpl metadataInstance = metadataCollector.buildMetadataInstance(metadataBuildingContext);
        return metadataInstance.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
}
```

The problem is that I never make it past the instantiation of InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl, instead I get two warn messages:

> No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections

> Could not obtain connection to query metadata

Followed by an UnsupportedOperationException which claims that "The application must supply JDBC connections".

Those warn/error message are very irritating because I am specifically required to not connect to the database. I want to note here that no such connection was required in Hibernate 4.3.11 either.

For the sake of research I attempted to run the code *with* a DB-connection by manually supplying one via `cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:<myUser>/<myPassword>@localhost:1521:SAT");`, and while this leads to issues further down the line, at least the example code that I provided worked fine.

So my question is: How can I instantiate an InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl without providing a database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was missing the following code directly below the instantiation of the StandardServiceRegistry:

```
    DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl impl = new DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl();
    impl.setDataSource(new NoReadTimeoutDataSource(db));
    impl.configure(Collections.emptyMap());
    
    ServiceBinding<ConnectionProvider> binding = ((ServiceRegistryImplementor) serviceRegistry)
            .locateServiceBinding(ConnectionProvider.class);
    binding.setService(impl);
```